# Polygon movement towards certain point libGDX

Tags: libgdx, android, collision-detection

I recently started using the Polygons but I'm have struggle as I'm trying to make a Polygon move towards the center of my screen, although I don't know how.
Here's the code I have(**What I'm trying to accomplish here is to make the balls spawn randomly by every side of the screen and make them go towards the middle of the screen to collide against a square**):

```
public class Game extends com.badlogic.gdx.Game implements Screen{

private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture Ball;
private Texture Up;
private OrthographicCamera cam;
private int score;
private String showScore;
private BitmapFont scoreFont;
private Sprite upSprite;

private Polygon square;

private Array<Polygon> balls1;
private Array<Polygon> balls2;
private Array<Polygon> balls3;
private Array<Polygon> balls4;

private Polygon ball1 = new Polygon();
private Polygon ball2 = new Polygon();
private Polygon ball3 = new Polygon();
private Polygon ball4 = new Polygon();

@Override
public void create(){

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    Ball = new Texture("energyball.png");
    Up = new Texture("up.png");

    upSprite = new Sprite(Up);

    upSprite.setOriginCenter();
    upSprite.setX(615);
    upSprite.setY(340);
    upSprite.setRegionWidth(64);
    upSprite.setRegionHeight(64);

    square = new Polygon(new float[] {
            upSprite.getX(), upSprite.getY(),
            upSprite.getX(), upSprite.getY() + upSprite.getHeight(),
            upSprite.getX() + upSprite.getWidth(), upSprite.getY() + upSprite.getY(),
            upSprite.getX() + upSprite.getWidth(), upSprite.getY()
    });

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, 1280, 720);

    upSprite.setPosition(upSprite.getX(), upSprite.getY());

    square.setOrigin(upSprite.getX(), upSprite.getY());

    // calls the functions to spawn balls randomly
    balls1 = new Array<Polygon>();

    balls2 = new Array<Polygon>();

    balls3 = new Array<Polygon>();

    balls4 = new Array<Polygon>();

    score();


    //if the screen is touched sprite rotates 90 degrees clockwise
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter() {

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {

            upSprite.rotate(-90);
            square.rotate(-90f);
            return true;
        }
    });


}


//shows score
private void score() {

    score = -4;
    showScore = "Score: 0";
    scoreFont = new BitmapFont();

}


//creates the balls and sets their position as well as the random timer for each
private void spawnBalls1() {

    ball1.setPosition(MathUtils.random(639, 641), 720);
    ball1.setScale(32, 32);
    balls1.add(ball1);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

}

private void spawnBalls2() {

    ball2.setPosition(0, MathUtils.random(359, 361));
    ball2.setScale(32, 32);
    balls2.add(ball2);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

private void spawnBalls3() {

    ball3.setPosition(MathUtils.random(639, 641), 0);
    ball3.setScale(32, 32);
    balls3.add(ball3);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

private void spawnBalls4() {

    ball4.setPosition(1280, MathUtils.random(359, 361));
    ball4.setScale(32, 32);
    balls4.add(ball4);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

@Override
public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    cam.update();

    //draws the game itself as well as the balls on the screen
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.begin();

    upSprite.draw(batch);

    //draws the balls
    for (Polygon ball1 : balls1) {

        batch.draw(Ball, ball1.getX(), ball1.getY());
    }

    for (Polygon ball2 : balls2) {

        batch.draw(Ball, ball2.getX(), ball2.getY());
    }

    for (Polygon ball3 : balls3) {

        batch.draw(Ball, ball3.getX(), ball3.getY());
    }

    for (Polygon ball4 : balls4) {

        batch.draw(Ball, ball4.getX(), ball4.getY());
    }

    scoreFont.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    scoreFont.draw(batch, showScore, 25, 100);

    batch.end();

    // if the time minus the time of the last ball spawn is less than x then spawn another ball in a random place
        if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) {

            switch (MathUtils.random(4)) {

                case 0:
                    spawnBalls1();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    spawnBalls2();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    spawnBalls3();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    spawnBalls4();
                    break;
            }
        }
    Iterator<Polygon> iter1 = balls1.iterator();
    while(iter1.hasNext()) {

        Polygon balls1 = iter1.next();
        balls1.getY() -= 350 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(balls1, square)) {

            score++;
            showScore = "Score: " + score;
            iter1.remove();
        }

    }

    Iterator<Polygon> iter2 = balls2.iterator();
    while (iter2.hasNext()) {

        Polygon balls2 = iter2.next();
        balls2.x += 550 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(balls2, square)) {
            score++;
            showScore = "Score: " + score;
            iter2.remove();
        }

    }


    Iterator<Polygon> iter3 = balls3.iterator();
    while(iter3.hasNext()) {

        Polygon balls3 = iter3.next();
        balls3.y += 350 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(balls3, square)) {

            score++;
            showScore = "Score: " + score;
            iter3.remove();
        }
    }

    Iterator<Polygon> iter4 = balls4.iterator();
    while(iter4.hasNext()) {

        Polygon balls4 = iter4.next();
        balls4.x -= 550 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(balls4, square)) {

            score++;
            showScore = "Score: " + score;
            iter4.remove();
        }

    }

}
```

And I'm getting an error here:

```
balls1.y -= 350 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

balls2.x += 550 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

balls3.y += 350 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

balls4.x -= 550 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
```

**Basically move this ball to the square**

[image]

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Comment: _error: y has private access in Polygon_ for every single one of them respectively

Comment: That suggests you have a problem with your scope. Have you added the public/protected modifier on your instance variables? ( public Array<Polygon> balls1; and public Polygon ball1 = new Polygon(); )

Comment: i just did and keeps giving me the same error

Comment: Please edit to reflect the actual problem you're trying to solve. This seems to have nothing to do with "movement toward a point" and far more to do with "I can't get this thing to compile".

Comment: Perhaps you should read into and learn some general debugging and error message interpretation before going into game development.

Answer (score 2):

> error: y has private access in Polygon

This simply means, that the `y` field is private in the Polygon class. Instead of trying to use `balls1.y` to reach that variable, use `setPosition(float x, float y)`, `getX()` and `getY()`

Comment: If I use any of those I don't think it will make the ball move towards the square, but now after changing it I get this error: 
 _java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0_

Comment: @gafflx If you don't know what that means, then you should learn java

Comment: I know what it means, and I think what is causing that is the fact that I did this:`balls1.setPosition(ball1.getX(), ball1.getY())`, then did `balls1.getY() -= 550 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();`

Comment: but I cant use `balls1.getY()` with `-= 550 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();`

Comment: @gafflx You need to use `ball1.setPositon(ball1.getX(), ball1.getY() - 550 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime())`

Comment: It expects a variable, I dont know which one

Comment: @gafflx Which one do you speak about?

Comment: @gaffix Actually, I noticed there's a translate function, then simply do ball1.translate(0, -550)

Comment: yeah that makes sense! although I keep getting the same error about the array, Ive tried to change the array nut nothing works

Comment: @gafflx But wich arraylist do you use when that error comes up